# JSF view is not updated after delete with ajax command button when using two controller classes

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

What's the best way to update model and refresh a view containing a list of items when using two Java Classes, one with view logic to display the list and another class with the delete logic (Goal was to keep classes lean),  after an item in the list is deleted by clicking a PrimeFaces commandButton on its row?

```
<ui:repeat var="row" value="#{hroc.siblingRows}">
    <ui:repeat var="sibling" value="#{row}">
        <p:commandButton update="@all" action="#{oCDelete.delete(sibling)}"/>   
  ...
```

the delete works fine but for me to see the view updated I have to hit refresh on my browser.

**I now realize that the model attached to the view bean obviously hasn't been reloaded** so the `update="@all"` (or any other specific id) isn't going to do anything here.

Should I inject my OCDelete class into the view backing bean and then in that class have the `hroc.delete(sibling)` method that delegates over to the actual delete and then update my model?

Or do I have a redirect in the `OCDelete.delete` back to the facelet?

I am using view parameters `o:viewParam` and `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{hroc.init}" />` so this would need to be considered.

Comment: i remember having similar problems with @all . can you try updating using the particular id's of the related components?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using primefaces v5.3.5+, then you can use p:repeat instead of `ui:repeat`

```
<p:repeat id="sibling" var="row" value="#{hroc.siblingRows}">
   <p:repeat var="sibling" value="#{row}">
   <p:commandButton update="sibling" action="#{oCDelete.delete(sibling)}"/>
```

Else, put the `ui:repeat`s in a container (say `p:panel`), give it an id, and update using that id.

Comment: the repeat is not related to my issue, but thanks for pointing out the PrimeFaces tag.  I assume it is more robust